Chrome alert does not appear when launched by Selenium WebDriver
I recently updated my project to use chromedriver 127 with Chrome 127 and suddenly the alerts do not appear that I was expecting on page refresh when page has unsaved changes.
Note: Alerts are present on manual steps
How to make the browser show alert here using Selenium WebDriver?
Is this issue with Chrome that needs to be raised?
I found https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/14290 issue in Selenium marked closed with - https://issues.chromium.org/issues/42323796
Whenever active sessions is a list containing exactly one item, and that item is a HTTP session, but is not a BiDi session, then in the steps to fire beforeunload, implementations must act as if showing an unload prompt is likely to be annoying, deceptive, or pointless.
NOTE
This means that beforeunload prompts are never shown when there's an active HTTP-only session.

OnUnload is being deprecated in favor of pageHide and sendbeacon type handling... so it's worth embracing the more recent methods of dealing with this sort of thing... (without annoying and unreliable prompts) https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/deprecating-unload

I always thought the default for unExpectedAlertBehviour was "Dismiss and Notify". (You should be able to try/catch that on the refresh method... Notify=Throw) You might also try explicitly setting that with options.setUnHandledPromptBehavior. The W3C WebDriver standard applies to the drivers, not the browser. The NOTE there is actually sort of strange as the driver has no control over whether the prompt is shown (for a very brief period of time anyway)

I resolved this issue by switching to use the BiDi Remote Driver:  options.UseWebSocketUrl = true; (C#)
